# How do I import a CSV file into sqlite3 in Python without knowing ahead of time the number of columns?

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I am currently trying to import, using Python, a CSV file into a SQLite database using the top fields as column names, but I need to be able to import any CSV file, regardless of how many columns it has.  I know how to use the csv top row to create the column names, but every example I have seen with regards to importing a csv file into databases in python, the python program has specified the number of columns there will be. However, this program will have the user supply the csv file names in an input box, allowing them to select different ones, so I won't know ahead of time how many columns need to be assigned.  How would I go about making it so the program automatically detects the number of columns and defines the table accordingly?  So far, I have something like this (not exactly, but a good example), but it only has two columns by default.  Oh, and I will be changing it later to add an option for the user to input a filename to open, so don't worry about that (mostly implemented already in a different module).

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (col1, col2);")

with open('data.csv','rb') as fin: 

    dr = csv.DictReader(fin) #dr assigned value in DictReader
    to_db = [(i['col1'], i['col2']) for i in dr] #

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?);", to_db) 
con.commit()
```

UPDATE:
Code I have now is this:

```
import csv, sqlite3
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog  import askopenfilename






def choosefilename():
    return askopenfilename()



def main():
    con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

    csvFileName = choosefilename()
    cur = con.cursor()
    with open(csvFileName,'rb') as fin:
        data_csv = csv.DictReader(fin)
        column_count = len(list(list(data_csv))[0])
        create_table_statement = "CREATE TABLE t ("
        for column in xrange(1, column_count):
            create_table_statement = create_table_statement + 'col{0}'.format(column)
        create_table_statement = create_table_statement + ');'
        cur.execute(create_table_statement)
        [cur.execute('INSERT INTO t values ('+'%s,'*column_count[:-1]+')', d) for d in data_csv]



Button(text='File Open', command = choosefilename).pack(fill="x")
main()
```

It doesn't give an error per se, but it freezes when you try to exit the open file button box.

Comment: Currently getting this error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/CSVtoSQLite.py", line 8, in <module>
    data_csv = csv.read(fin)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use the pandas library, this could easily be achieved using two functions:

```
pandas.read_csv
```

which will return a dataframe object, and then use the Dataframe method

```
Dataframe.to_sql
```

to create your database. Pandas should be pretty smart about dealing with headers to your csv. You will likely just need to use the default arguments.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: I actually wanted to use Panda (I was familiar with it before hand and saw that it would have made this project very easy), but based on the way this program will ultimately work and the instructions I have, I will only be using Tkinter, sqlite3, and a couple other "library" modules.  Unfortunate because Panda would have reduced the amount of code I had to write lol.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
with closing(con.cursor()) as cur:
    with open('data.csv','rb') as fin:
        data_csv = csv.read(fin)
        column_count = len(list(list(data_csv)[0])
        create_table_statement = "CREATE TABLE t ("
        for column in xrange(1, column_count):
            create_table_statement = create_table_statement + 'col{0},'.format(column)
        create_table_statement = create_table_statement[:-1] + ');'
        cur.execute(create_table_statement)
        [cur.execute('INSERT INTO t values ('+'%s,'*column_count[:-1]+')', d) for d in data_csv]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just curious, but why didn't you use DictReader?

Comment: problem one was "with con.cursor() as cur:"  This caused an error.  Replaced it with cur = con.cursor, which fixed error.

Comment: after that I found other errors, but some of them I haven't been able to fix yet.

Comment: DictReader assumes you have a header and it's more strict than the standard csv.reader. Maybe you could leave **all** of your errors as comments and I'll look into them?

Comment: The errors I fixed, but now the program crashes without an error message.  To be honest, I think I'm the one who broke it, made a lot of changes to try to make it do more than I say here.

Comment: Again, post your code as is, with **all** the errors, and I'd be happy to take a look

Answer (score -1):

must there not a be a try before the WITH  ??

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
try:
    with closing(sqlite3.connect(":memory:")) as con:
```

also misted a )

```
column_count = len(list(list(data_csv)[0]))
```